# How to use a join to find customer groups with no customers in Oracle SQL?

Tags: sql, oracle

I have two tables: Customer and Cust_Group

There are 12 customer groups and there are some customers in each group and 0 in other groups. I don't understand how to use a join to find these customer groups with 0 customers.

```
Select CUSTG_NBR, CUSTG_NAME
from student.custgroup_6, student.customer_6
where Cust_GROUP  <> custG_Nbr
;
```

This was my thought, but it clearly doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can just check which customer group id doesnt appear in the customer table

select custg_name from cust_group where id not in (Select custg_nbr from customer)

Comment: This almost works, but the main problem is that the results give me duplicates. I'm not sure why.

Comment: select distinct custg_name from cust_group where id not in (Select custg_nbr from customer)

Comment: Thanks for the answer, though I forgot to mention that the attributes needed were in different tables. I used a Union to get the right answer. Will choose your answer though.